# import/include attribute from other XML

Tags: xml

Is it possible to include attribute and attribute value from other XML?
Lets imagine we have two XMLs:

common.xml

```
<profile>
   <library value="TEMP">
</profile>
```

library.xml

```
<technology>
   <library name="TECH">
</technology>
```

As result I want to include library name attribute from library.xml into common.xml:

```
<profile>
   <library value="TEMP" name="TECH">
</profile>
```

It's possible to use xpointer and then xmllint -xinclude, but in such case whole element will be included.

```
<xi:include href="library.xml" parse="xml" xpointer="xpointer(//technology/library[@name='TECH'])"
```

I'm looking for the same approach, but only for attribute...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to tag your language / software. XSLT can absolutely handle your request.

Comment: Parfait, thanks for an answer. I'm new to XSLT, could you point me to any examples, manuals, etc which help to solve the problem?